# Draw shaps of squares using PTB

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I want to draw 4 squares, side by side, using PTB for my experiment, but the code does not work..
Here is my code,

```
square_size = [0 0 50 50];               
squareXpos = [screenXpixels * 0.125 screenXpixels * 0.25 screenXpixels * 0.5  screenXpixels * 0.75];   
numSqaures = length(squareXpos);                 
allColors = [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1; 1 0 0];                      
allRects = nan(4, 4);                      
for i = 1:numSqaures                            
    allRects(:, i) = CenterRectOnPointd(square_size, squareXpos(i),  yCenter);             
end                            
Screen('FillRect', window, allColors, allRects);                        
Screen('Flip', window);                         
KbStrokeWait;
```

If anyone knows how I can fix this problem, please help me.

Comment: Please add the text of the error you get

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the error.

If I had to guess, there's probably something wrong with the format of the inputs.

Here's potential problems I noticed at first glance.

1. Psychtoolbox (unlike matlab) uses the RGB scale from 0 - 255 instead of 0 - 1. With your code all the colors will show up as black. Instead of [1,0,0] for red, use [255,0,0].
2. Your allColors matrix is nItems X 3(RGB), but the function wants it the opposite way. Instead of entering allColors, you need to transpose: allColors'.

If I'm struggling with pscyhtoolbox, the first thing I always check is the formatting of inputs. To get help about the appropriate format for the inputs, type:

```
Screen('FillRect?')
```